# I have issue when creating my first flutter app

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

After creating my app on flutter, I tried to create an app file from it ..
But I keep getting an error which says "flutter.bat failed to run. System cannot find the path specified at line1 char1"
I don't know if there's a solution to that.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGOxj.jpg)

Comment: Can you provide the result of the command `flutter doctor -v`.

Answer (score 0):

run flutter `doctor -v` and discard what it produces.
And try to fix your project, for this call
`flutter create project_name` for the folder where the root project is located.